# jQuery Created Nested List Based on Attribute

Tags: jquery, nested, html-lists

I get stuck when trying to implement recursive logic in jQuery--I don't have much practice with it. I have a simple need, which is to nest unsorted lists by class. What I have is two dynamic lists on a page (they're generated by two CAML queries). The first list will be the top level `<li>` and the second list will be nested. The first list has `<li>`s with numeric id's and the second list has `<li>`s with numeric classes that match the id's that they have to be nested under. i.e.:

```
<ul>
    <li id="10">Parent Item 1</li>
    <li id="14">Parent Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="10">Child 1</li>
    <li class="10">Child 2</li>
    <li class="14">Child X</li>
</ul>
```

There will be an undetermined number of parents and child `<li>`s over time. Also, if it's better to use a different attr than class for the children that's fine. Ultimately I'll want to add more classes for CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/rkCKT/

Assuming this markup:

```
<ul class="parents">
    <li id="10">Parent Item 1</li>
    <li id="14">Parent Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="children">
    <li class="10">Child 1</li>
    <li class="10">Child 2</li>
    <li class="14">Child X</li>
</ul>
```

this would work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul.children li').each(function(){
        probable_parent = $('ul.parents li#' + $(this).attr('class'));
        if (probable_parent.length)
        {
            if (!probable_parent.find('ul').length) probable_parent.append('<ul/>');
            $(this).detach().appendTo(probable_parent.find('ul'));
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Edit**:

As soon as you add any classes to the `.children li`s for presentational reasons, everything will be broken.

For this and half a million other reasons, if your document is HTML5, I strongly suggest using proper attributes for the parent-child relationship. Ideally, the markup would look something like this:

```
<ul class="parents">
    <li data-itemid="10">Parent Item 1</li>
    <li data-itemid="14">Parent Item 2</li>
</ul>
<ul class="children">
    <li data-itemid="10">Child 1</li>
    <li data-itemid="10">Child 2</li>
    <li data-itemid="14">Child X</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: +1 for jsfiddle. And good idea adding classes to the ul's, I didn't think of that.

Comment: Your code works great! Question for future reference: if I wanted to do this with a table instead of a UL, would it suffice just to replace UL with table and LI with tr?